# A way to hide a tag on mobile, but show the contained div

Tags: css

Is there a way to hide an a tag wrapping a `div`, but still display a `div`? I need the picture on mobile to be not clickable and trying to see if there is a way to do that without having to duplicate.

`display:none` on `<a>` hides the entire `div`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for pointer-events: none; this will not visually hide the element but will stop click events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events